# Identical interquartile ranges for distributions with different means and numbers of data points

Tags: distributions, boxplot

Consider these two distributions, representing ratings (in the range 0-9) given in an experiment for two different conditions A and B:

```
A = [6.75   7.65    0   0   9   0   9   9   9   0   0   0   9   9   0   9   9   0   7.65    0   1.8 8.55    0.45    5.85    3.6 0.45    1.35    1.8 3.15    9   1.8 4.95    0   0.45    2.25    0.45    4.05    3.6 1.35    0.9 1.35    0.9 0   5.85    6.3 6.3 5.4 0.45    0.9 0.9 0.45    0.45    0.45    0.45    1.35    8.55    8.55    4.95    4.5 5.4 8.1 7.2 0.9 0.9 3.15    4.5 2.25    0.9 7.65    1.8 5.85    5.85    0.9 2.7 7.65    4.95    4.95    7.2 6.3 7.2 5.85    6.75    2.7 6.75    2.7 5.85    6.75    4.95    5.4 4.95    4.05    6.3 6.3 3.15    3.6 3.6 2.7 4.5 5.4 2.7 8.1 3.15    4.05    4.95    4.5 4.95    4.95    1.8 1.35    3.15    4.05    4.95    4.05    4.05    6.3 5.85    4.95    5.4 6.3 3.6 7.2 2.7 1.35    6.75    6.75    1.8 1.8 6.75    6.75    5.85    5.85    5.85    3.6 4.5 0.45    4.95    3.6 2.25    4.5 4.95    3.6 4.5 3.6 4.5 4.95    4.05    3.6 4.5 5.85    4.5 5.4 4.95    3.15    0   9   4.5 0   2.7 7.65    5.85    5.4 0   7.65    7.2 8.1 6.75    8.55    8.1 2.25    0   7.2 7.2 6.75    4.5 3.15    7.2 4.5 6.3 2.25    2.7 4.5 6.75    2.25    6.3 2.7 4.5 2.7 3.15    3.6 4.95    3.6 2.25    4.5 4.95    3.6 4.5 3.6 4.5 4.95    4.05    3.6 4.5 5.85    4.5 5.4 4.95    3.15    7.2 6.3 0.9 2.7 6.3 2.7 6.75    5.4 6.75    5.4 6.75    7.65    6.3 5.85    2.25    5.85    4.95    8.1 4.95    6.3 6.3 0.45    3.15    5.4 5.85    4.95    3.6 2.7 4.95    5.4 7.65    1.8 5.4 2.25    5.4 3.15    4.5 9   4.5 0   0   2.25    1.8 9   0   4.5 6.75    6.75    9   1.35    2.25    4.5 2.25    6.3 4.5 2.25    5.4 0.9 5.4 6.3 2.25    5.4 0   5.4 6.3 5.85    2.25    5.85    0.45    1.8 7.2 7.2 6.75    6.75    7.65    7.2 7.2 2.7 2.25    7.2 2.7 7.65    7.65    1.8 2.7 0.9 5.4 7.2 9   2.7 6.75    2.25    8.55    1.8 9   7.2 1.8 9   0   0   0.45    1.8 0   9   0.9 6.3 0.9 7.65    7.2 3.6 3.6 3.6 6.3 1.8 4.95    3.15    6.75    3.6 3.15    4.5 5.85    8.1]
```

and

```
B = [1.8    9   9   0   0   0   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   0   0   0   9   0   0   0   9   0   0   0   0   0   9   0   9   0   0   9   9   0   0   0   0.45    8.1 8.55    8.55    8.1 8.1 0.45    8.1 5.85    0.45    0   5.4 8.55    9   1.35    0   3.6 5.4 0   0   6.75    1.35    8.1 8.55    0.45    6.75    5.85    9   8.1 8.1 0   0   0   0   0   0.45    3.15    1.8 0.45    7.65    3.15    5.85    1.8 5.85    0   5.4 6.75    0.9 6.3 0   7.2 0.9 0.45    1.35    7.65    2.25    7.2 6.3 0   0.9 7.2 0.45    0   2.25    0.45    4.5 0.9 1.35    1.35    8.1 6.3 0.9 1.8 7.65    5.4 8.1 7.65    5.85    6.75    5.85    6.75    7.2 7.65    3.6 2.7 2.25    2.25    0.9 6.75    5.85    2.25    1.35    6.75    6.3 0   1.8 2.7 1.35    2.25    4.5 1.35    2.25    7.2 2.7 6.75    2.7 6.75    2.25    2.25    1.35    6.3 4.5 8.1 6.75    6.75    3.15    3.6 6.75    5.85    5.4 7.65    4.5 6.75    4.5 4.95    4.5 6.3 5.85    3.6 2.7 7.2 6.75    6.3 6.3 4.95    4.95    4.95    5.4 4.95    4.05    3.6 4.05    1.35    3.6 8.1 2.7 5.85    6.3 8.1 4.05    4.05    7.2 6.75    5.4 3.15    2.25    2.7 2.7 1.8 2.7 5.85    3.6 4.95    5.85    5.4 3.15    5.4 5.85    7.2 6.3 6.3 2.7 5.4 5.4 3.15    5.4 2.7 5.85    4.5 5.4 4.95    4.95    5.4 4.5 4.5 3.6 0.45    4.95    3.15    4.95    4.95    5.4 6.3 5.4 4.95    5.85    5.4 5.4 5.4 6.3 5.85    5.4 3.6 5.85    3.6 4.05    3.15    6.75    3.15    5.4 5.4 5.85    3.15    6.3 6.3 1.35    6.3 6.3 2.25    1.8 0   6.75    1.8 6.3 4.05    5.85    6.75    5.85    3.6 4.05    6.75    6.3 0.45    0.9 0   4.5 6.75    7.2 4.5 4.5 4.5 3.6 4.05    4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 1.8 3.15    4.95    5.4 4.5 4.5 4.95    4.95    4.5 4.05    5.85    4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 5.4 3.6 1.8 4.5 5.85    3.6 4.5 4.5 4.5 1.8 4.5 5.4 4.5 6.75    7.2 0.45    7.2 0   4.5 0   9   9   0.9 6.75    0.9 0   0   0   4.5 7.2 1.8 4.5 6.75    6.3 6.3 7.2 0   6.75    6.75    3.15    9   0.45    0   1.35    3.15    4.5 4.5 0   7.65    7.2 7.65    1.8 7.2 2.7 4.5 2.7 1.8 2.25    4.5 6.75    7.2 2.25    2.25    2.25    6.75    3.15    4.5 7.65    2.7 5.85    2.7 3.15    2.7 2.7 5.85    5.85    5.85    1.8 3.15    2.25    2.25    6.3 4.5 4.5 4.5 3.6 4.05    4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 1.8 3.15    4.95    5.4 4.5 4.5 4.95    4.95    4.5 4.05    5.85    4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 5.4 3.6 1.8 4.5 5.85    3.6 4.5 4.5 4.5 1.8 4.5 3.15    7.2 1.35    6.3 7.2 1.8 6.3 6.3 5.4 2.7 7.2 5.85    5.4 3.15    5.85    4.5 5.85    2.25    2.25    5.85    2.7 8.1 7.2 1.8 1.35    5.4 2.7 6.3 6.75    3.15    6.3 5.4 6.3 1.35    7.2 6.75    3.15    1.35    0.9 1.8 7.2 0.45    6.75    1.8 1.8 5.85    5.4 4.05    5.85    3.15    4.95    5.4 6.3 7.2 0.9 2.25    4.05    5.4 6.3 5.85    2.7 3.6 4.95    3.6 1.8 5.4 4.05    5.85    3.6 5.4 3.6 1.8 0   0   0   4.5 9   4.5 6.75    4.5 9   9   6.75    4.5 5.85    1.8 1.8 5.85    7.2 0   0.9 0   4.5 4.5 4.5 6.75    0.45    2.25    4.5 4.5 1.35    4.5 4.5 1.8 6.75    4.5 2.25    1.35    5.85    6.3 2.25    5.85    5.4 5.4 1.8 1.8 4.95    4.95    0.9 5.4 4.5 5.4 4.5 1.8 4.5 0.9 4.5 5.85    5.4 5.4 1.8 2.25    0   2.7 0.45    2.25    5.4 3.6 0   2.25    0.9 0.9 3.15    6.75    4.5 6.3 3.15    7.2 6.75    2.7 1.8 2.7 6.3 5.4 2.7 3.15    6.3 6.3 5.85    3.15    6.75    2.25    7.2 3.15    1.35    6.3 1.35    4.95    4.95    0.9 5.85    5.85    5.4 2.7 6.3 7.65    0   0   4.5 7.2 5.85    0   2.25    2.25    9   0   1.35    7.2 9   2.25    9   0   5.85    5.85    2.7 9   7.2 0   9   9   0   0   5.85    1.35    5.4 7.2 7.2 8.55    8.55    5.85    6.3 5.85    4.5 6.3 5.4 3.6 7.2 7.65    5.4 5.85    6.75    3.6 2.7 6.3 8.55    5.85    5.85    6.3 3.6 2.25    4.5 3.15    6.3 5.85    0.45    1.8 6.3 0.9 ]
```

DIstributions A and B above have identical interquartile ranges (4.05), even though they have different means and numbers of data points, as per the plots below. Now, I am well aware that rank-based statistics like the median and IQR are relatively indepentent of the mean and sample size, but stimuli in conditions A and B were actually quite different in the experiment, so for this reason too, I did not at all expect the IQRs to be exactly the same.

This apparent paradox must either in fact be something very simple that I am for some reason not getting; or an actual statistical paradox that I'm hoping someone can explain (Googling returned nothing helpful).

boxplots
[image: boxplots]

raw data
[image]

Comment: Please state your question and explain what your word "paradox" is referring to.  As far as I can tell, your post tells us you weren't expecting something that occurred.  How would you like us to respond?

Comment: Good point. My surprisal is a bit difficult to put into a coherent question on this occasion. I will try to update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes: but *what is your question??*  You still haven't asked one and there's no "apparent paradox" in sight.

Comment: The question is how can it be (OR: do you find this surprising too) that these IQRs are _exactly_ the same for two distributions that have the same 0-9 range but are are otherwise entirely different in their number of ratings and what the ratings represent (what sort of stimulus was being responded to, A or B)

Comment: Well, you give an explicit example of how it can be.  This is no surprise with discrete data: there are only ten possible choices for either quartile, after all.  It's even less a surprise in any study where the treatment exhibits little or no difference: the quartiles *should* be the same!  It would help, then, for you to articulate some *basis* or *reason* for your surprise and show us this is anything other than a subjective reaction.

Comment: Why _should_ they be the same as long as different skews and spreads can be expected in the distribution corresponding to each condition? I would not have thought the reason why this result is surprising to me will not also be obvious to others, but maybe I am just betraying my ignorance with statistics.

Comment: By "different skews and spreads can be expected" I mean that _there is no good reason_ to expect that these would be identical, so as to make for identical IQRs. I.e., the default should be, we get different IQRs, and yet we don't. Hopefully that makes my question a bit clearer.

Comment: You null hypothesis in this research is that the distributions are the *same,* so I am mystified by your statements that you expect *different* results.

Comment: Just thinking about distributions A and B as vectors of numbers, their descriptive means would indeed be expected to be different, at least if looking at enough many decimal points (e.g. it is 4.39 for A, 4.30 for B). So I remain baffled that these vectors' IQRs would be the same up to the last decimal point. Could this just be a case of rounding error, relating to the finite number of possible values (namely, 10)?

Answer (score 3):

You wrote

> This apparent paradox must either in fact be something very simple
> that I am for some reason not getting; or an actual statistical
> paradox that I'm hoping someone can explain

It's the first. There really isn't any paradox. To see this more easily, note that the IQR is not affected by values outside the quartiles. Let's make a toy example:

```
Set 1:   1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 7
Set 2:   -100 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 100
Set 3:   -100 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 8
```

All have the same IQR (at least, if I've put in enough 3s, 4s, and 5s, if not, feel free to add more). And you could add a lot more 3's, 4's and 5's and not change the IQR.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! It's easy to see why the IQR is not affected by values outside the quartiles. I guess what I still don't understand is why the quartiles themselves (or rather the differences between them) are the same, given that the two data sets I indicated are a lot more granular than your toy example.

Comment: They are clearly *not* "more granular:" your graphics show only about 20 distinct values among hundreds or thousands of observations.